# Codeigniter delete

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404, codeigniter-url

I am trying to delete some data from my database via delete button in codeigniter...I did some research and came up with this link in my view...

```
<td><a href='hockey/deleteskater/" . $row->id . "'>Delete</a></td>
```

and this function in my controller

```
public function deleteskater($id){
        $this->load->database();
        $this->db->delete('skaters', array('id' => $id));
    }
```

But I get a 404 Not Found Page...what am I doing wrong?

Comment: post your Controller code and details of url that you tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because:

1. The url likely gets interperted wrong (all the segments appended to the current url)
2. More important: you didn't print out the variable...just '$row->id' as a string. That's not php-html interpolation

Should be:

```
<td><a href="<?php echo site_url("hockey/deleteskater/" . $row->id);?>"
     onclick="return confirm('Delete content?');">Delete</a></td>
```

I took the liberty to at least add an onclick alert so that you don't inadvertitely delete something just by misclicking. 
Also, destructive action should be carried through a POST request (and a CSRF token to increase security).

Answer (score 1):

```
<td><a href='hockey/deleteskater/" . $row->id . "'>Delete</a></td>
```

Should be

```
<td><a href='hockey/deleteskater/<?php echo $row->id ?>'>Delete</a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default [Codeigniter anchor](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

```
<td><?php echo anchor("hockey/deleteskater/'. $row->id . '", "Delete"); ?></td>
```